# Questions about password security in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
function password_encrypt($password) {
    $hash_format = "$2y$10$";   // Tells PHP to use Blowfish with a "cost" of 10
    $salt_length = 22;        // Blowfish salts should be 22-characters or more
    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}

function generate_salt($length) {
    // Not 100% unique, not 100% random, but good enough for a salt
    // MD5 returns 32 characters
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));     
    // Valid characters for a salt are [a-zA-Z0-9./]
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);    
    // But not '+' which is valid in base64 encoding
    $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);      
    // Truncate string to the correct length
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);
    return $salt;
}
```

Do you guys thnk this is secure? What could have been done differently? What's maybe easier to use to secure a password and hash it?

Comment: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` does the trick and are easy to use and very secure, compared to what you just did.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Easy to use? Where would i have to put it in my code? or how would you write it? :/

Comment: `<?php 

  $password = "YourStrongPassword";


  $hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //hashing the password.


  $pass2 = $password; //this could be from a userinput

  // verifying the hash.

  if(password_verify($pass2,$hash)){

    echo "passwords match";
  }else{

    echo "passwords does not match";
  }            
?>`

Comment: You can check the manual for more about password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: sha1 with a 10 characters salt is much enough ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blowfish itself is already really secure. One thing: don't do too much hashing etc. to generate a salt. Also, why not make it easier and use `password_hash`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Example:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n";
```

And to check a password:

```
if (password_verify($password_nonhashed, $password_hashed)) {
```

You don't need to hash a salt too much with blowfish. Just use `sha1` hash for a salt if you really don't want to use `password_hash`.

Good luck!

Comment: The salt option for the password_hash() function has been deprecated so that the developers do not generate their own (usually insecure) salts. The function itself generates a cryptographically secure salt.